# How to check for html5 video support?

Tags: flash, video, html

Is there any JavaScript or any other way of checking for html5 video support?

Answer (score 17):

use:

```
<script>
alert(!!document.createElement('video').canPlayType);
</script>
```

if it alerts true implies that your browser supports HTML5 video tag

Here is the url to check HTML5 Browser compatibility http://www.html5test.com/
Open the url in your browser to test how well your browser supports html5

Comment: IE11 returns true, but doesn't play hls stream/video with videojs. Having a flash fallback is not an option. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Just a little refinement of sweets-BlingBling's answer : sorry - I can't comment yet :(

```
var isHTML5Video = (typeof(document.createElement('video').canPlayType) != 'undefined') ? true : false;
```

or even simpler (thanks digitalBath - as always I can't see the wood for the trees :) )

```
var isHTML5Video = (typeof(document.createElement('video').canPlayType) != 'undefined');
```

Comment: For what it's worth, "{boolean_expression} ? true : false" is no different than "{boolean_expression}"

Comment: Just curious if this line of code will generate java script errors when debugging a page, IF the browser actually was not capable of parsing "document.createElement('video').canPlayType", because it was too old for HTML5. I guess it would always generate "false" for the variable, but would it choke in doing so?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at Modernizer: http://www.modernizr.com/

There, you get APIs as easy as

```
if (Modernizr.video) {
  // html5 video available
}
```

But many more features and more suitable APIs as well.

Answer (score 2):

I use a slight variation of @sweets-BlingBling's answer, which is:

```
var hasVideo = !!document.createElement('video').canPlayType &&
               !!document.createElement('video').canPlayType('video/mp4')
```

This also checks whether the media type `'video/mp4'` is actually playable (change this if your video has another media type, like `'video/webm'` or `'video/ogg'`). The method returns an empty String if the video definitely cannot be played and `'probably'` or `'maybe'` (actually, both results mean `yes` in most instances) otherwise. I had to add this for Chrome 41 (seemingly used in google crawler), which has `canPlayType`, but cannot play `mp4` videos.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to embed the html5  tags, and then put the alternate video viewer within the video tags as a "fallback".  The fallback will get displayed if a browser doesnt recognize the  tag.  Its not strictly 'detecting' html5 video support, but may suit your needs.

```
<video src='...'>
    <embed flash player instead>
</video>
```